# Create a Delivery Docket (Custom Record) linked to a Purchase order like an item receipt but for outgoing items

Tags: workflow, netsuite, purchase-order

Our company manufactures products from raw board materials like PLYWOOD and MDF. We outsource a lot of our work to be painted by 3RD PARTY companies. I understand there are ADDITIONAL MODULES that may enable the functionality I'm about to explain, but I doubt we will be upgrading or implementing any new modules anytime soon.

Currently, our process is as follows:

- We create a purchase order.
- However, we can't track when the job has gone out to that painter.
- We can only record when it comes back (gets received).
- We create an item receipt by receiving the items that come back at that time.

I'm not very good at coding (very very very basic understanding), so I was hoping there was a way I could utilise a WORKFLOW and a CUSTOM RECORD. This custom record would link to the purchase order and copy the items from the purchase order to the customer record. The purpose of this would be to create a delivery docket. This delivery docket would simply record what items have been taken or sent to our painter. Once the items come back, we would then use the native function of item receipt.

Currently, I have managed to create a button on a Purchase Order (called 'Create Delivery Docket') via a Workflow. I did also manage to get the button to open the new record I created, but the record is blank and basically has no relevant information, I don't know how to populate the record with the parts or items on the Purchase Order. I just hope there is a reasonable solution that's not too difficult to set up. Although I can't replicate it.

However, that is as far as I have gotten. I would appreciate any type of feedback or suggestions.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, it seounds like you need [Outsourced Manufacturing](https://suiteanswers.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/91095/loc/en_US). Netsuite will let you create a purchase order sent to a supplier. The item "purchased" needs to be an assembly item that includes the raw material items, and optionally a number of "Subcontract labour" items to cover the cost charged by the supplier as part of a BoM. The raw materials are transferred to the subcontractor via an inventory transfer or transfer order, and a work order and purchase order + item receipt to "build"  the assembly at the subcontractor, then another transfer order or inventory transfer to bring the assembly from there to your local location. This feature needs a number of features, including manufacturing.

If you wanted to create this functionality outside the standard feature then I suggest you employ a recognised Netsuite developer to create the required custom scripts, custom records, and workflows.

Comment: Thank you, Simon.
I'm aware there are native features in existing modules (manufacturing) but we don't have the money to cover that at the moment. I understand it's something that could eventually save us money in the long term but, but I was hoping for a different solution that only covers a small aspect of the whole manufacturing module. 
I was just after some guidance on how to make a custom record that acts a separate item transfer/outsource record from a purchase order or to see if anyone has made something similar.